# refactor Node code for DRY (do not repeat your self)

Tags: node.js, refactoring

have the code bellow

```
exports.list_tum_izinler = function (req, res) {
    var _user = toknHelper.getUserFromToken(req);
    izinler.list_Izinler(_user.username, sendResult);

    function sendResult(data) {
        if (data instanceof Error) {
            res.status(500).send(data.message);
            return;
        }
        res.status(200).send(data);
    }
}

exports.Izin_Counts= function (req, res) {
    var _user = toknHelper.getUserFromToken(req);
    izinler.Count_Izinler(_user.username, sendResult);

    function sendResult(data) {
        if (data instanceof Error) {
            res.status(500).send(data.message);
            return;
        }
        res.status(200).send(data);
    }
```

Here am trying to refactor the code to DRY, I want to extract this section

```
 function sendResult(data) {
        if (data instanceof Error) {
            res.status(500).send(data.message);
            return;
        }
        res.status(200).send(data);
    }
```

as an external function and send data and res parameter to that function. the point here that the data parameter returns from the function and res parameter is an external parameter, so how i can send res parameter with data parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create some other file... myFunction.js:

```
const sendResult = ({ res, data }) => {
  if (data instanceof Error) {
    res.status(500).send(data.message);
    return;
  }
  res.status(200).send(data);
};

module.exports = sendResult;
```

Then, require it in to your current code:

```
const sendResult = require('./myFunction');

exports.list_tum_izinler = function (req, res) {
    var _user = toknHelper.getUserFromToken(req);
    izinler.list_Izinler(_user.username, sendResult);
}
```

You need to realize that you are using this function as a callback, thus if you are wanting to feed this function into `izinler.Count_Izinler(_user.username, sendResult)`, then you need to modify that function to properly provide it the response.. thus you'd need to also pass the response down into that function and give it to the callback whenever you need:

```
const Count_Izinler(username, res, callback) => {
  // dunno what this function does... but maybe it gets data somewhere
  let data = 'some data';
  callback({res, data});
}
```

But, if you're going to do that, you might as well just require that function into the implementation itself, and not in the higher-order function and remove it as a callback:

```
const sendResult = require('./path/to/myFunction');

const Count_Izinler(username, res) => {
  // dunno what this function does... but maybe it gets data somewhere
  let data = 'some data';
  return sendResult({res, data});
}

const list_izinler(username, res) => {
  // dunno what this function does... but maybe it gets data somewhere
  let data = 'some data';
  return sendResult({res, data});
}
```

Then, you'd invoke those functions like so:

```
izinler.list_Izinler(_user.username, res);
```

But, to be honest, this creates mostly a mess of code and confuses the heck out of people.  It becomes far less maintainable.  Your future self will hate you for doing this.  I suggest you just return the `data` from `Count_Izinler` and `list_Izinler`, then feed that into your `sendResult`... like so:

```
const sendResult = require('./myFunction');

exports.list_tum_izinler = function (req, res) {
    var _user = toknHelper.getUserFromToken(req);
    const data = izinler.list_Izinler(_user.username); // <-- modify this function to only take user name, and RETURN whatever it does, which is the "data"
    return sendResult({res, data});
}

exports.Izin_Counts= function (req, res) {
    var _user = toknHelper.getUserFromToken(req);
    const data = izinler.Count_Izinler(_user.username); // <-- modify this function to only take user name, and RETURN whatever it does, which is the "data"
    return sendResult({res, data});
}
```

You unfortunately omit other pieces of code, such as `list_Izinler` and `Count_Izinler` for someone to fully give you a 100% accurate answer.  Please provide more code snippets of those other functions if you want a clearer answer.

Edit: Using async/await..

```
exports.list_tum_izinler = async function (req, res) { // <-- specify the function as async...
    var _user = toknHelper.getUserFromToken(req);
    const data = await izinler.list_Izinler(_user.username); // <-- use "await" before the invocation.  This function must return a promise in order for this to work.  If it does not, list_Izinler needs to be modified to return a promise... mostly a trivial thing to do...
    return sendResult({res, data});
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your nice response. actually Count_Izinler and list_Izinler make a DB connection witch returns async operation therefor i thought it will be more easy to hand async with callback functions. i did not try your second approach, but would like to know if its a good idea to handle async operations rather then messy in code.

Comment: Use the newer async/await.  It's just far superior.  I'll update post to show you an example of what the syntax.